# Uv Unwrap only shows one side

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

Hello guys i am unwrapping my face mesh but in UV image editor only shows one side of the mesh! how can i fix? can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because you have a Mirror Modifier active. Your figure only has that one side until you Apply the Mirror to it. Click the eye symbol on your Mirror Modifier and you will se what I mean. Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you i didnt realise at first! i toggled to object mode and applied mirror , i switched to obj mode and unwrapped again, now it showed me the two sides! thank you so much

Comment: Not a problem, I'm still a noob myself (only been learning for maybe 3 weeks.) So I figured this out like 3 days ago :)

Comment: omg you still much better than me, ive spent almost 1 year trying to model a face and still it doesnt look so good , i am still trying to figure out the best geometry for low poly to look sharp and clean for game creation but still realy hard... i just realised that we cant rely on tutorials because if you follow then it will either look like their model or turn out a monster as you are trying to model a face on behalf of other face lol  my main tutorial still blenderella , i just find very impressive the way angela models her character in every detail possible